# Adding elements to columns inside for-loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to add values using append to an array while I iterate the columns. So I want it so that for z=0, it fills out column 0 in 'bubblelife', then when z=1 starts, it fills column 1.

I am using two for loops to scan row by row (using index variable i) and using index variable z to move to the next column.

The excel file this is importing is formatted as shown below, with first column for date stamp, and 4 subsequent columns for data.

```
3/26/2018 0:01  0   94.98629761 99.9942627  0
3/26/2018 0:18  0   94.98629761 0   0
3/26/2018 0:18  94.99441528 94.98629761 99.9942627  64.99035645
3/26/2018 0:36  89.9921875  94.98629761 95.99212646 0
3/26/2018 0:36  89.9921875  94.98629761 0   94.98666382
```

I am trying to get the time data when the state changes from 0 to non zero value and vice versa, to calculate how long the state remains ON (how long the speed remains non-zero).

I get an error on this line:

```
 bubblelife[:,z].append(time[i])
```

The full code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

file = 'RackTime.xlsx'
x1=pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="Dataset1")
time = x1.iloc[:,0]
racklife = x1.iloc[:,1:5]
bl_racklife = racklife !=0                                                      


bubblelife=[];prematurebreak=[]; 
np_bubblelife = np.array(bubblelife); np_prematurebreak = np.array(prematurebreak)
for z in range(0,3):
    for i in range(1, len(bl_racklife)):
            if (bl_racklife.iloc[i-1,z]!=bl_racklife.iloc[i,z] ):
                 bubblelife[:,z].append(time[i])
            if bl_racklife.iloc[i-2,z]!= bl_racklife.iloc[i-1,z] and bl_racklife.iloc[i,z]!= bl_racklife.iloc[i-1,z]:
                 np_prematurebreak[:,z].append(time[i-1])
```

Desired result: 
Array 'bubblelife' with four columns of time data

```
3/26/2018 0:18  3/26/2018 2:22  3/26/2018 0:18  3/26/2018 0:18
3/26/2018 1:29  3/26/2018 2:40  3/26/2018 0:36  3/26/2018 0:36
3/26/2018 1:47  3/26/2018 3:15  3/26/2018 0:54  3/26/2018 2:58
3/26/2018 2:04  3/26/2018 3:33  3/26/2018 2:04  3/26/2018 4:44
3/26/2018 3:51  3/26/2018 3:51  3/26/2018 2:22  3/26/2018 7:06
3/26/2018 4:08  3/26/2018 4:08  3/26/2018 2:40  3/26/2018 7:59
3/26/2018 5:02  3/26/2018 5:02  3/26/2018 2:58  3/26/2018 8:16
3/26/2018 5:19  3/26/2018 5:55  3/26/2018 3:15  3/26/2018 8:34
3/26/2018 5:37  3/26/2018 6:12  3/26/2018 3:33  3/26/2018 10:20
```

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`. This is because `list.append` is an *in-place* operation. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: I am trying to add 'time' values at the particular index at the end of my column in 'bubblelife', but I also want to be able to iterate the columns, therefore using the index variable 'z'. I edited my code a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I can't run any of your code, so I am struggling to help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have included my full code with a sample of what the excel import looks like. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Please show desired result.

Comment: Edited the post, thanks.

Comment: the indentation is off in your code, that is not the problem, or is it?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it

Comment: bubblelife is a regular python array. you can't use advanced indexing on it (`[:,z]`). (side note: i'd avoid using append on an ndarray)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Made bubblelife a numpy array and tried doing this `np_bubblelife[:,z] = time[i]` but still get an error for the array having too many indices.